# PL/SQL utl_http get xml

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to implement a very simple `PL/SQL` procedure able to get an `xml` file from the web.

The `PL/SQL` code is the following one:

```
SET serveroutput ON SIZE 40000
set escape on

create or replace procedure testProc as 

url   VARCHAR2(256) := 'http://www.mypage.com/testXML.xml';

req   sys.utl_http.req;
resp  sys.utl_http.resp;
txt   VARCHAR2(100); 

begin
  req := sys.utl_http.begin_request(url,'GET','HTTP/1.0'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');   
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-length', length(txt));
  resp := sys.utl_http.get_response(req);

  LOOP
    sys.utl_http.read_line(resp, txt, TRUE);
    dbms_output.put_line(txt);
  END LOOP;
  sys.utl_http.end_response(resp);

EXCEPTION WHEN sys.utl_http.end_of_body THEN
sys.utl_http.end_response(resp);

end testProc;
/
```

I successfully built the procedure by SQLPlus.
However when I try to execute it I get the following error:

```
SQL> exec testProc;
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/trentad/testXML.xml<br />
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is weird as the xml file I'd like to read is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Given that the same code, without the `_ set_header_  functions` works fine for a normal `HTML`, providing correctly its source page, please could anybody explain me why it does not work with a simple `xml` file?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set content-type and content-length in your GET request ? Your GET request can't have any body (request entity). It is not a POST.

```
utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');   
utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-length', length(txt));
```

You have to do this for response.

Comment: Ok, yes you are right. However, how to set the header for the response? Maybe it is a stupid question, but I did not find any document or tutorial to handle this use case.

Comment: The page at `http://www.mypage.com/testXML.xml` is the one that will send the response and set the response headers. Your PL/SQL code is just sending the request. I think you do not have to set response headers in your PL/SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your question on lkuty's answer that you are looking for the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header.  This informs the server what type(s) you will accept in response.